# Does github limit the number of personal access tokens per user

Tags: github, github-enterprise

Using Github Enterprise, I have a service/bot account where I'd like to generate a number of Personal Access tokens and provide to a number of teams.

Is there any limit in how many Personal Access Tokens can be generated per user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, there is no limit, but if you want to be sure, you should ask either the GitHub support team or on the GitHub community forums.

GitHub itself has such a bot account and PATs are frequently used there, but do be aware that the UI may be a little (or, depending on how many tokens you issue, very) slow, since it isn't designed for people to have huge numbers of PATs.

You may find it more desirable to use deploy keys if you're accessing a repo, since these have a smaller scope (one repository) and won't have the UI problems mentioned above, but of course that won't work for the API.

Comment: Thank you! I hadn't considered the UI implications.